# VSCode remove TypeScript annotations?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to select a TypeScript code block and copy a JS version (without invalid JS syntax) for quick testing in a browser.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you have any script in your package.json that invokes tsc?

Comment: @user no we do not, typically we've been using babel and just `yarn run tsc` for type checking

Comment: why not just invoke tsc and copy from the generated js?

Comment: I considered this, but our code is bundled and uses hot reload via webpack, I'm just looking for a way to remove additional typescript markup like colons and triangle brackets

Comment: related: there exists a possible future where you might not need to do anything and can copy-paste as is :) https://github.com/tc39/proposal-type-annotations. in the meantime, I'd look for an extension that does this, or [write your own](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension).